# Problemas para alinhar o banner no centro

Tags: html, css

estou trabalhando com parallax e nao estou conseguindo deixar a img src da div header alinhada no meio, nao sei oq esta acontecendo. 
Ja tentei mexer na margin, mas nada acontece.
Alguem pode dar um help?

```css
body {
 font-family: Tahoma;

}



.container{
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background:#303
 font-size: 24px; 
 padding: 25px; 
 
}

.parallax {
 background:url(../imgs/background.jpg) no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 height: 350px;
 
}

#div.header{
 width: 800px;
 height: 140px;
 background:#F3E8BE;
 margin:0px auto;
}


div#header h1{
 margin-top: 30px;
 display: block;
 float: left; 
     
}

ul#nav{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding-left: 0px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 130px;
}

ul#nav li{
 float:left;
 margin-left: 50px;
 
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<h1><img src="imgs/banner.png"/></h1>

<ul id="nav">
<li>Inicio</li>
<li>Gamemode</li>
<li>Fórum</li>
<li>Sobre</li>
<li>BPE e BPF</li>
<li>Sistema de troca de dinheiro</li>
</ul>


</div>



<div class="container">
 
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
<div class="parallax">













</div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pq vc está colocando uma imagem dentro de um `h1`? Essa tag deve ser usada para títulos.

Comment: Eu estou seguindo uma aula como base para aprender parallax e ele utilizou em H1. 
Qual tag deveria usar?

Comment: Pois é. Me parece semanticamente incorreto, mas... Se quiser centralizar a imagem, basta colocar `text-align: center;` nesse `h1`.

Comment: Outra coisa: o `h1` já é `display: block` por padrão, portanto não precisa colocar isso no CSS. Em vez do h1, vc poderia usar uma div mesmo.

Comment: Não ta indo.... esse lorem ipsum parece estar impedindo meu banner de ficar centralizado.

Comment: Opa...coloquei como div e ele deu uma alinhada melhor agora ein, mas nao centralizou ainda.
O lorem ipsum está um pouco transbordado agora, mas o banner e o menu ficaram na posiçao que eu queria, um respeitando o outro.

Comment: Tira o `float: left`

Comment: nossa! muito obrigado!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Coloca esse h1 com o banner dentro de um vid, depois da um id para ela, no css dessa div que voçê criou. da um display: flex; aling-items: center;